# Insert into database with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I am currently developing a website in ASP.NET. From one of the pages users can send messages to other users and their managers. I am trying to store the messages in the database which I have created for test purposes. I am using the following string in C# to store into the datbase. However none of the values are getting stored.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Messages (Id, UserName, Message2, Sentdate)" + " VALUES(" + User.Identity.GetUserId() + User.Identity.Name + txtMessage.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString() +");"
```

My knowledge on C# is not the greatest so please excuse me if I'm making an obvious mistake.

If someone can tell me where I'm going wrong that would be great, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You've only shown a string declaration - which is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, by the way. You should show us the code which is trying to actually *execute* the SQL... and learn about parameterized SQL.

Comment: Are you executing the query? Making a connection to the database? Show us the code you used to store the data in your database. We need more than just the query.

Comment: You are not generating a valid SQL statement since the values you are trying to insert are not comma-separated and you are missing quotes around string and date values. That's for the creation of the statement. Then it seems you are not executing it.

Comment: ^^^^ ...which is also easily avoided via the use of parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this one:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Messages (Id, UserName, Message2, Sentdate)" + 
" VALUES(" + User.Identity.GetUserId()+", " + 
User.Identity.Name +", "+
txtMessage.Text +", " +
DateTime.Now.ToString() +");"
```

However this approach is extremely exposed to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

For this reason, I suggest you use a parameterized query. [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) you will find a useful example one how to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've used parameterized query before and it worked. So I think i'll use it again.

Comment: @Izzy you welcome dude. I just reported this, because I didn't know that you know about.